# DFS Recursion Woes

Tags: java, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

I'm trying to write an algorithm to determine whether two nodes in a directed graph are connected. Simple enough, but I'm getting hung up on my recursive implementation of DFS.

My solution, which works, is quite ugly:

```
public static boolean isConnected (Node src, Node dst) {
    HashSet<Node> visited = new HashSet<>();
    return isConnectedHelper(src, dst, visited);
}

private static boolean isConnectedHelper(Node src, Node dst, HashSet<Node> visited) {
    if (src.equals(dst)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!visited.contains(src)) {
        visited.add(src);
        for (Node neighbor : src.neighbors) {
            if (isConnectedHelper(neighbor, dst, visited))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Notably, this line is ugly:

```
        if (isConnectedHelper(neighbor, dst, visited))
            return true;
```

Is there a better way to write this? The main trouble is getting the algorithm to continue searching if there's a miss, but to stop searching once you have a match. I imagine there's a clean way of doing this...?

Comment: Why do you think it's ugly? Looks ok to me.

Comment: The only ugly part about that line is the lack of curly braces. Looks fine otherwise.